# How to force user to enter values again and again until input is in certain range

Tags: python

I am REAL newbie and trying to learn some coding in Python (only experience which I have is from free codeacademy on line exercises). This code works correct if I entering correct inputs. However, I would like to  force "user" (myself), to enter values of Byte1 and Byte2 again and again until correct input is finally entered. For example, if I enter two values which is out of allowed range ..GGGG,JJJJ, script just say about error and continues.
If anyone would be interested to help me to solve it, please, put comments or give more details about solution so I can understand how and why. Thank You.

Here is code

```
import re

def check(X):
    if not re.match("^[0-FFFF]*$", X):
        print "Error! Only HEX values allowed!"
    elif len(X) != 4:
        print "Error! Only 4 characters allowed!"

while True:
    byte1_start = raw_input("Enter byte1 start value: ")
    check(byte1_start)
    byte1_end = raw_input("Enter byte1 end value: ")
    check(byte1_end)
    byte2_start = raw_input("Enter byte2 start value: ")
    check(byte2_start)
    byte2_end = raw_input("Enter byte2 end value: ")
    check(byte2_end)
    break

print ("All is ok!")
```

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand your question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are rather close:

```
def getValue(cmd):
  While True:
    answer = raw_input(cmd)
    if check(answer):
       return answer
    else:
       print "your input is not valid"
```

and reqwrite your check-function a bit:

```
def check(X):
  if not re.match("^[0-FFFF]*$", X):
    print "Error! Only HEX values allowed!"
    return False
  elif len(X) != 4:
    print "Error! Only 4 characters allowed!"
    return False
  return True
```

and your programm now reads

```
byte_1_start = getValue("Enter byte1 start value: ")
byte_1_end = getValue("Enter byte1 end value: ")
...
```

Comment: `if check(answer)` *What?* The function doesn't return anything.

Comment: sorry, I just read the name and assumed the rest.. BTW: Your _What?_ sounds a bit harsh for such a small error.

Comment: I upvoted, but I think two functions here is too much for such a small task, especially a function called 'check()' - check what for what?

Answer (score 1):

You should have `check` keep track of all the errors that could possibly exist, then return all errors. Either that or simply check to see if it passes or not -- don't try and give a reason.

Option 1:

```
def check(byte):
    tests_msgs = [(lambda byte: re.match("^[0-9A-F]*$", byte), "Error! Only HEX values allowed!"),
                  (lambda byte: len(byte) == 4, "Error! Only 4 characters allowed")]
    return [msg for test,msg in tests_msgs if not test(byte)]

bytes = []

for i in range(4):
    while True:
        byte = raw_input("Enter byte{} start value: ".format(str(i)))
        errs = check(byte)
        if not errs:
            bytes.append(byte)
            break
        else:
            for err in errs:
                print err
```

Option 2:

```
def check(byte):
    tests = [lambda byte: re.match("^[0-9A-F]*$", byte,
             lambda byte: len(byte) == 4]
    return all(test(byte) for test in tests)

bytes = []

for i in range(4):
    while True:
        byte = raw_input("Enter byte{} start value: ".format(str(i)))
        if check(byte):
            bytes.append(byte)
            break
        else:
            print "Some generic error message"
```

Note also that your regex won't work as intended. `[0-FFFF]` is not all four-digit hex values. You're looking for:

```
/^[0-9A-F]*$/i
# re.compile(r"^[0-9A-F]*$", re.I)
```

But you could also combine both errors with one regex and skip checking `len(X)` afterward:

```
/^[0-9A-F]{4}$/i
# re.compile(r"^[0-9A-F]{4}$", re.I)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use just use all with a set returning a boolean and functions to avoid having to repeat all input if the user makes a single mistake:

```
def check(x):
    st = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
    if all(ch.upper() in st for ch in x):
        if len(x) != 4:
            print "Error! Only 4 characters allowed!"
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        print("Invalid input {}".format(x))
        return False

def byte1_start():
    inp = raw_input("Enter byte1 start value: ")
    while not check(inp):
        inp = raw_input("Enter byte1 start value: ")
    return inp

def byte1_end():
    inp = raw_input("Enter byte1 end value: ")
    while not check(inp):
        inp = raw_input("Enter byte1 end value: ")
    return inp

def byte2_start():
    inp = raw_input("Enter byte2 start value: ")
    while not check(inp):
        inp = raw_input("Enter byte2 start value: ")
    return inp

def byte2_end():
    inp = raw_input("Enter byte2 end value: ")
    while not check(inp):
        inp = raw_input("Enter byte2 end value: ")
    return inp

for chk in [byte1_start, byte1_end, byte2_start, byte2_end]:
    chk()

print("All good")
```

Answer (score 0):

import re

condition = True

def check(X):

```
status = True
if not re.match("^[0-FFFF]*$", X):
    print "Error! Only HEX values allowed!"
    status = False
elif len(X) != 4:
    print "Error! Only 4 characters allowed!"
    status = False
return status
```

while condition:

```
byte1_start = raw_input("Enter byte1 start value: ")
b1s = check(byte1_start)
byte1_end = raw_input("Enter byte1 end value: ")
b1e = check(byte1_end)
byte2_start = raw_input("Enter byte2 start value: ")
b2s = check(byte2_start)
byte2_end = raw_input("Enter byte2 end value: ")
b2e = check(byte2_end)

if (b1s and b1e and b2s and b2e):
    condition = False
```

print ("All is ok!")